# Bootstrap 4 Toggle icon on button via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 4 page set up with collapsible accordion table. Each has a fa-times-circle icon. When users When a user clicks on this button, that icon needs to change to fa-plus-up. Plss help!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          toggleCircle = function(button) {
          $(button).find('span').toggleClass('fas fa-times-circle fa-plus-circle');
    }
</script>

 <button class="btn text-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" onclick="toggleCircle(this)"> <span class="fas fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: 
`if ($(e.children).attr("class").includes('down')) {` to detect whether or not the icon was arrow down or not and then use:

```
$(e.children).removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
$(e.children).addClass("fa-chevron-up");
```

to [add](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [remove](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) the class to up/down.

```js
toggleCircle = function(e) {
  if ($(e.children).attr("class").includes('down')) {
    $(e.children).removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $(e.children).addClass("fa-chevron-up");
  } else {
    $(e.children).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
    $(e.children).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn text-dark collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" onclick="toggleCircle(this)"> <span class="fas fa-chevron-down"></span>
```